# Trying to use DDRescue on a live copy of Ubuntu, how do I install DDrescue?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, ddrescue

I am using a "live" version of Ubuntu on my computer, 20.04LTS. I want to install DDrescue. I have run these terminal commands in order:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install gddrescue
```

I get this back:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ddrescue-gui : Depends: python-wxtools but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python2.7 but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

What do I do now? I tried "`sudo install python-wxtools`" and "`sudo install python2.7`" and both don't work.

I have 0 experience with linux and it is frustrating the heck out of me.

Comment: Which exactly package you are trying to install? On the system with connected internet `gddrescue` installs normally. But `ddrescue-gui` packages [is not presented in official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ddrescue-gui). Do you use third-party repository (or PPA)  or local deb-package to install it?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `ddrescue-gui` package [is not presented in official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ddrescue-gui).

To install this package you should connect computer to internet and then add third-party repository, really in this case - Personal Package Archive (PPA) [from launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Ehamishmb/+archive/ubuntu/myppa?field.series_filter=focal). The complete reproducible method then will be the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hamishmb/myppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gddrescue ddrescue-gui
```

To launch the application use its launcher in the menu named *DDRescue-GUI* or `python3 /usr/share/ddrescue-gui/DDRescue_GUI.py` command directly.